# How to setup DLNA sorting

Tags: sorting, metadata, dlna

What is the best way using a windows server (as the source) to provide an easy to access listing of available videos for use by DLNA enabled television sets (specifically Samsung)?
I've created folders for each show and season but my TV or Windows 8 itself is displaying options such as "Genre and Rating"; I have no idea where its looking for this metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a different server that will allow you to configure the layout of your library. Give [KooRaRoo Media](http://www.kooraroo.com) a try - you can create various dynamic (smart) playlists and hierarchical dynamic trees that will catalogue your shows automatically.

Comment: A non-Microsoft solution looks like it may be the best answer. I haven't had much luck with the built-in server as of yet.